# Mains transformer replacement for Denon PMA-320

Tags: amplifier, transformer, audio, repair

I am servicing a Pioneer Audio amplifier (PMA-320) which sadly has an open primary winding in the mains transformer. As you may know, original replacements are unobtainium therefore, I am planning to retrofit a conventional toroidal transformer, therefore, I would like to ask you for feedback to confirm if I am on the right track.

According to the technical specs from this amplifier, it is capable of delivering 60W+60W into 8 ohms (0.05% THD) and a maximum of 90W+90W into 4 ohms (1% THD). The VAC output voltage before rectification is 36VAC per secondary winding. Once rectified it should be of about +/- 49VDC.

[image: Transformer section PMA-320]

Taking a maximum power delivery of 90W per channel, the transformer to be fitted should have a minimum VA rating of 180VA and two secondary windings of 36 V (when loaded). If my simple math is correct... ;)

Would a 225VA transformer be close enough to substitute the original transformer? Taking into account some current overhead for transients when listening at high volume levels.

The closest output voltage that I could find here in the UK is 35VACx2 which I suppose won't make a great difference on B+/B-.

The next important point to consider is that the original transformer was potted from the factory and shielded in a metallic enclosure:

[image]
[image]

I am totally aware that I should mount the new transformer to the chassis using the right mounting kit (rubber insulator and washer) to avoid shorting the outputs, however, my next issue is going to be dealing with the tight space constraints inside the amp. Having said that, two questions come to my mind:

1. Should I try to shield the transformer using a metallic harness/enclosure?
2. Should I consider potting it myself?

Cheers

Comment: First order of business is open circuit voltage. What is it and can your amplifier survive that?

Comment: As for shielding, thin sheet metal will only affect E-fields, and whenever I hear shielded transformers, I think about clueless audiophiles using gold plated mains cables.

Comment: I assume that you mean 'open circuit voltage' from the transformer? Not every datasheet indicates this value, however, even if the rectified and filtered voltage was somewhat high, the output transistors are rated at +/- 140V (2SC3855/2SA1491). The main filters are only rated at 56V, though so I must be careful that the rectified voltage does not exceed this value.

Comment: It might be worth checking the original transformer to see if it has an internal thermal fuse. It *might* be repairable.

Comment: Agree with Transistor, if the gunk is removable you'll probably find a blown thermal fuse or maybe a bad solder joint between the transformer coil and the colored wires.

Comment: _”somewhat high”_ That’s unfortunately not a very engineering term. Can you quantify? If you are going to break it from anything, it won’t be due to the VA rating of the transformer (save for some very edge case with limited SOAR and designers with balls of steel), but open circuit voltage. Too close and a little mains variation? POOPF! Magic smoke.

Comment: @winny sorry, but I cannot quantify what I do not have on my test bench. Any number that I throw here will be highly speculative. I will base my calculations on what the datasheet from the manufacturer indicates. On the other hand, the transformer won't ever be under an unloaded condition, isn't it? Upon turning the switch on, the transformer will be immediately loaded by the amplifier (resistors, capacitors, transistors, etc). Also, I normally use a variac when testing my devices, so, I will definitely slowly turn up the voltage up when testing the new transformer.

Comment: @Transistor and bobflux you are absolutely right and I also thought about that, however, the potting compound is hard as a rock. It is not possible to remove it without damaging the transformer. It seems like Denon's engineers did not want it to be repairable by any means :(

Comment: That load is very small. Measure the open circuit voltage of the replacement transformer with a multimeter.

Comment: @Winny Don't know about Denon but I certainly know of mu-metal shielding on some other hi-fi amplifier transformers. But it doesn't like a lot of mechanical shock : removing the transformer may damage the shielding properties unless it's annealed again (which involves 800C in a hydrogen atmosphere).

Comment: Most epoxies loose strength at 90C or so. These temperatures shouldn’t affect the windings. Shove it in the oven at 80C for 30mins and see if you can pick out the epoxy. It’s a messy job. As for your choice of toroidal - seems like a close match. No need to pot and toroidals supposedly have low magnetic leakage, so you should be ok.

Comment: Got a feeling 225VA would be too lightweight to drive 2x90W into 4 ohms, but probably OK if you restrict it to 8 ohm speakers. If that casing is mu-metal, expect some hum without it.

Comment: It’s fused with a 2A fuse, so it is less than 460W. 225VA is not unreasonable methinks.

Comment: if you buy a transformer that weighs the same as the old one, it should have enough VA for this application. I base this judgement on the tendency of engineers to use the minimum amount of material needed to meet the specification, and the tendency of technology to progress monotonically.

Comment: Very valuable comments here, guys. I will try (without great expectations) to find the thermal fuse inside the old transformer. I might just blast it at 400 C (842F) and see if the potting compound softens a bit. Thanks for the feedback, people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to update you and close my post with the final result of my repair.

I decided to fit a new transformer. The specs from the one I chose are 300VA 2x35V, precisely [this](https://www.cricklewoodelectronics.com/300VA-0-35V-0-35V-Toroidal-Transformer.html) one.

Here is the final look:

[image: 300VA mounted on a custom 3D printed bracket]

Mounting it was a bit of a challenge due to space constraints. The original transformer was quite slim and thus it had to be raised about 1 inch to clear the capacitors, wires and other boards. It was safely secured and isolated with the included mounting plates and rubber washers.

To do so, I designed (in Onshape) and 3D printed a custom support with an off-centre mounting hole:

[image: custom riser]

As a result, the amplifier is now back to life and working even better than with the original transformer!

I evaluated the power output and I was able to squeeze a clean output at 120W per channel onto a resistive load (8 Ohms, though it got quite warm :S).
Testing it with my pair of Denton 85th the sound was very crisp and warm. Success!

Comment: Great post. Thank you. Can you advise how you wired the grey, red, yellow and black wires to the rectifier board? There are 3 pins on the board and 4 wires.